# Loading specific module from concatenated file using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Trying to use the [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js) library in a project, but having trouble with RequireJS. URI's readme indicates that it works with requirejs - which is true when you're using the source - but not when using the [minified/concatenated distribution file](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/blob/gh-pages/src/URI.min.js) on its own - as you would in production.

Their build process scoops several libraries into a single `.min` file, and they all define themselves as modules.

No matter how I require that script, the only argument I receive is the first module in their distribution file (`IPv6`) which is not what I need.

Is there something trivial I'm missing?

```
<script>
require.config({
    paths: {
        urijs: 'dist/URI'
    }
});

require(['urijs'], function(URI) {
    console.log(URI);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the module you need?

Comment: URI itself. I'd consider custom-building to leave out the optional modules but we're using this through `bower` and were looking for an easy utility, not something we have to custom compile/minify

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the minified file cannot be used because it is not correctly built. All the `define` calls in it are anonymous whereas they should include the module name. If they had, you'd be able to use the minified file.

To get it to work, in the `paths` configuration, I've put `urijs` to point to the directory that contains all the individual `.js` files of the modules, and then I require `URI.js` as `'urijs/URI'`. I let `r.js` minify it for distribution of my code.

I've installed it with `npm` but I've just checked with `bower` and the process should be exactly the same.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the cause, thanks. I don't use `r.js`, we're copying minified files out of bower libraries when we deploy to production, which means I a) need to include these extra files and b) I still can't concat them, meaning I'd have four new http requests for a single library - which isn't acceptable. I recently got a reply from the URI author: "if you're using require, you may want to use the source files". Unbelievable.